# Dynamically create new textbox when another is filled in

Tags: javascript, jquery

To illustrate: http://sas98.user.srcf.net/guestlist/

I want a new input field to be created when the user types something in the guest list field at the bottom.

Is it possible to do this as opposed to having to press a button with onClick?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a blur event that gets fired when a first input box looses focus. THere can be an additional check to make sure someone put some text to the first input field, if there is a value add a new input field

```
$('#guest_list_input').blur(function() {
    if($(this).val().length>0) {
         $('#myPlaceWhereIWantToAddANewInputField').append('<input value='test' name='test' />');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to append a new input after `focus`, `blur` or `change` events.

My choice would be to create a field on `focus` (so the user can switch to it by pressing Tab) and optionally remove the empty fields on `blur` events. Possibly with some fancy fadeIn/Out effects.